# error while loading shared libraries: ? : cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory while running runmqakm

Tags: node.js, ssl, ibm-mq

I have set up node.js to put message into local MQ queue. The set up is on windows machine. Am trying to create .kdb file for SSL, using MQI client.

I have set the PATH variable to bin folder of 9.3.0.0-IBM-MQC-Redist-Win64 (C:\9.3.0.0-IBM-MQC-Redist-Win64\bin). Am able to put or get message into local queue.

Also I have set this variable MQIJS_NOREDIST using export command, so as to avoid downloading everytime.

When I run below command

```
runmqakm -keydb -create -db clientkey.kdb -pw tru5tpassw0rd -type pkcs12 -expire 1000 -stash
```

I get the error

```
C:/9.3.0.0-IBM-MQC-Redist-Win64/bin/runmqakm.exe: error while loading shared libraries: ? : cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: You need to add the `lib64` directory to your `PATH`

Comment: Hi JoshMc, i think you meant bin64. If i add bin64 to PATH, then i get the error
                                                                                                                                                     
C:/9.3.0.0-IBM-MQC-Redist-Win64/bin64/runmqakm.exe: error while loading shared libraries: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll : cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: Try running `strmqtrc -e -t detail -t all`, recreate the error, run `endmqtrc -a` , run ` cd %HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%\IBM\MQ\data\trace`.  Look for the TRC file that is for runmqakm and try and find out what library it is failing to load.   Also 9.3.0.0 is a brand new version, it is possible there could be an issue with the redist zip, download and try the same with 9.2.0.6 redist as a control to see if you get the same error.